# What is the difference between "Don't keep activities" and a Configuration change?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-viewmodel

I am using View Model architecture component to handle the UI states and contain Business logic. It is known it survives a configuration change, but when Don't keep activities option is turned on in Developer options, a new instance of View Model is created. The activity onDestroy is called in both the cases then what is the difference between the two?

I am maintaining a state machine in the View Model and face issue in restoring it since View Model does not survive this. I cannot use Instance state since it has complex objects.

Following logs are from a sample project I tried. This has an Activity `TestActivity` which contains a fragment `TestFragment`, and `TestFragment` contains two fragments `TestStateAFragment` and `TestStateBFragment`

**TestActivity.kt**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test)

    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container_fragment_test, TestFragment())
            .commitAllowingStateLoss()
    }
}
```

**TestFragment.kt**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    Timber.i("onViewCreated")
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container_state_a, TestStateAFragment.newInstance())
            .commitAllowingStateLoss()
        childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container_state_b, TestStateBFragment.newInstance())
            .commitAllowingStateLoss()
    }
}
```

**TestStateAFragment.kt**

```
private val compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
private lateinit var viewModel : TestStateAViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    Timber.i("onCreate")
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, TestStateAViewModelFactory())
        .get(TestStateAViewModel::class.java)
    Timber.i(viewModel.toString())
}
```

**Screen rotation :**

```
(TestStateAFragment.kt:101)#onPause: onPause
(TestStateBFragment.kt:66)#onPause: onPause
(TestFragment.kt:72)#onPause: onPause
(TestActivity.kt:45)#onPause: onPause
(TestStateAFragment.kt:105)#onStop: onStop
(TestStateBFragment.kt:70)#onStop: onStop
(TestFragment.kt:76)#onStop: onStop
(TestActivity.kt:50)#onStop: onStop
(TestActivity.kt:23)#onSaveInstanceState: onSaveInstanceState
(TestFragment.kt:55)#onSaveInstanceState: onSaveInstanceState
(TestStateAFragment.kt:55)#onSaveInstanceState: onSaveInstanceState
(TestActivity.kt:54)#onDestroy: onDestroy
(TestStateAFragment.kt:110)#onDestroyView: onDestroyView
(TestStateBFragment.kt:75)#onDestroyView: onDestroyView
(TestFragment.kt:81)#onDestroyView: onDestroyView
(TestStateAFragment.kt:115)#onDestroy: onDestroy
(TestStateBFragment.kt:80)#onDestroy: onDestroy
(TestFragment.kt:86)#onDestroy: onDestroy
(TestFragment.kt:17)#onAttach: onAttach
(TestFragment.kt:18)#onAttach: TestFragment{984b690 (625e084e-68d8-46d6-9527-dfe2694fa5c1) id=0x7f07004c}
(TestFragment.kt:23)#onCreate: onCreate
(TestStateAFragment.kt:30)#onAttach: onAttach
(TestStateAFragment.kt:31)#onAttach: TestStateAFragment{1ff9e9a (f73d9a4a-4fb0-4e1c-b6b0-220941525ae2) id=0x7f07004d}
(TestStateAFragment.kt:39)#onCreate: onCreate
(TestStateAFragment.kt:44)#onCreate: com.example.lifecycleviewmodel.fragment.states.a.TestStateAViewModel@afc805d
(TestStateBFragment.kt:27)#onAttach: onAttach
(TestStateBFragment.kt:28)#onAttach: TestStateBFragment{908b1a7 (a5fa2bce-9b3b-4474-ae2a-0a891f289f65) id=0x7f07004e}
(TestStateBFragment.kt:33)#onCreate: onCreate
(TestActivity.kt:34)#onStart: onStart
(TestFragment.kt:34)#onCreateView: onCreateView
(TestFragment.kt:40)#onViewCreated: onViewCreated
(TestStateAFragment.kt:67)#onCreateView: onCreateView
(TestStateAFragment.kt:73)#onViewCreated: onViewCreated
(TestStateBFragment.kt:44)#onCreateView: onCreateView
(TestStateBFragment.kt:50)#onViewCreated: onViewCreated
(TestFragment.kt:61)#onStart: onStart
(TestStateAFragment.kt:90)#onStart: onStart
(TestStateBFragment.kt:55)#onStart: onStart
(TestActivity.kt:40)#onResume: onResume
(TestFragment.kt:66)#onResume: onResume
(TestStateAFragment.kt:95)#onResume: onResume
(TestStateBFragment.kt:60)#onResume: onResume
```

**Don't keep activities off :**

```
(TestStateAFragment.kt:101)#onPause: onPause
(TestStateBFragment.kt:66)#onPause: onPause
(TestFragment.kt:72)#onPause: onPause
(TestActivity.kt:45)#onPause: onPause
(TestStateAFragment.kt:105)#onStop: onStop
(TestStateBFragment.kt:70)#onStop: onStop
(TestFragment.kt:76)#onStop: onStop
(TestActivity.kt:50)#onStop: onStop
(TestActivity.kt:23)#onSaveInstanceState: onSaveInstanceState
(TestFragment.kt:55)#onSaveInstanceState: onSaveInstanceState
(TestStateAFragment.kt:55)#onSaveInstanceState: onSaveInstanceState
(TestActivity.kt:30)#onRestart: onRestart
(TestActivity.kt:34)#onStart: onStart
(TestFragment.kt:61)#onStart: onStart
(TestStateAFragment.kt:90)#onStart: onStart
(TestStateBFragment.kt:55)#onStart: onStart
(TestActivity.kt:40)#onResume: onResume
(TestFragment.kt:66)#onResume: onResume
(TestStateAFragment.kt:95)#onResume: onResume
(TestStateBFragment.kt:60)#onResume: onResume
(TestStateAFragment.kt:101)#onPause: onPause
(TestStateBFragment.kt:66)#onPause: onPause
(TestFragment.kt:72)#onPause: onPause
(TestActivity.kt:45)#onPause: onPause
(TestStateAFragment.kt:105)#onStop: onStop
(TestStateBFragment.kt:70)#onStop: onStop
(TestFragment.kt:76)#onStop: onStop
(TestActivity.kt:50)#onStop: onStop
(TestActivity.kt:23)#onSaveInstanceState: onSaveInstanceState
(TestFragment.kt:55)#onSaveInstanceState: onSaveInstanceState
(TestStateAFragment.kt:55)#onSaveInstanceState: onSaveInstanceState
```

**Don't keep activities ON :**

```
(TestStateAFragment.kt:101)#onPause: onPause
(TestStateBFragment.kt:66)#onPause: onPause
(TestFragment.kt:72)#onPause: onPause
(TestActivity.kt:45)#onPause: onPause
(TestStateAFragment.kt:105)#onStop: onStop
(TestStateBFragment.kt:70)#onStop: onStop
(TestFragment.kt:76)#onStop: onStop
(TestActivity.kt:50)#onStop: onStop
(TestActivity.kt:23)#onSaveInstanceState: onSaveInstanceState
(TestFragment.kt:55)#onSaveInstanceState: onSaveInstanceState
(TestStateAFragment.kt:55)#onSaveInstanceState: onSaveInstanceState
(TestActivity.kt:54)#onDestroy: onDestroy
(TestStateAFragment.kt:110)#onDestroyView: onDestroyView
(TestStateBFragment.kt:75)#onDestroyView: onDestroyView
(TestFragment.kt:81)#onDestroyView: onDestroyView
(TestStateAFragment.kt:115)#onDestroy: onDestroy
(TestStateBFragment.kt:80)#onDestroy: onDestroy
(TestFragment.kt:86)#onDestroy: onDestroy
2019-09-18 20:30:10.503 31473-31473/com.example.lifecycleviewmodel W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@d382041
(TestFragment.kt:17)#onAttach: onAttach
(TestFragment.kt:18)#onAttach: TestFragment{544b1c5 (625e084e-68d8-46d6-9527-dfe2694fa5c1) id=0x7f07004c}
(TestFragment.kt:23)#onCreate: onCreate
(TestStateAFragment.kt:30)#onAttach: onAttach
(TestStateAFragment.kt:31)#onAttach: TestStateAFragment{ea5f827 (f73d9a4a-4fb0-4e1c-b6b0-220941525ae2) id=0x7f07004d}
(TestStateAFragment.kt:39)#onCreate: onCreate
(TestStateAFragment.kt:44)#onCreate: com.example.lifecycleviewmodel.fragment.states.a.TestStateAViewModel@fa43f72
(TestStateBFragment.kt:27)#onAttach: onAttach
(TestStateBFragment.kt:28)#onAttach: TestStateBFragment{f66bb79 (a5fa2bce-9b3b-4474-ae2a-0a891f289f65) id=0x7f07004e}
(TestStateBFragment.kt:33)#onCreate: onCreate
(TestActivity.kt:34)#onStart: onStart
(TestFragment.kt:34)#onCreateView: onCreateView
(TestFragment.kt:40)#onViewCreated: onViewCreated
(TestStateAFragment.kt:67)#onCreateView: onCreateView
(TestStateAFragment.kt:73)#onViewCreated: onViewCreated
(TestStateBFragment.kt:44)#onCreateView: onCreateView
(TestStateBFragment.kt:50)#onViewCreated: onViewCreated
(TestFragment.kt:61)#onStart: onStart
(TestStateAFragment.kt:90)#onStart: onStart
(TestStateBFragment.kt:55)#onStart: onStart
(TestActivity.kt:40)#onResume: onResume
(TestFragment.kt:66)#onResume: onResume
(TestStateAFragment.kt:95)#onResume: onResume
(TestStateBFragment.kt:60)#onResume: onResume
```

So where do these two scenarios differ exactly and is there a way to determine which one took place?

Comment: Where is the ViewModel created?

Comment: @DavidWasser In onCreate method of TestStateAFragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a **configuration change** occurs, the Android framework will call `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` on your `Activity`. You can return any object you want to. Then Android will destroy your `Activity` and immediate create a new instance. In `onCreate()` of the new instance you can call `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`. If the `Activity` was recreated due to a configuration change, the object that you returned from `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` will be returned here. Otherwise the call returns `null`. In this case you can tell when your `Activity` was recreated due to a configuration change, and when it was (re)started for other reasons.

The **developer option** "Don't keep activities" is not something that you usually have to deal with, as normal users should never have it enabled. You can use it for testing purposes to ensure that your `Activity` properly recovers in case Android decides to kill it off.

In reality, Android usually doesn't kill off individual activities. If Android needs to recover resources from background applications **it usually just kills off the entire OS process**. However, I have recently seen some situations on some devices where Android does indeed kill off individual activities when an app is in the background. When the user then returns to the app, Android will recreate the `Activity`. In this case you will get `null` returned from `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`, but you would get a non-null `Bundle` in the `onCreate()` call and you would also get a non-null `Bundle` in the `onRestoreInstanceState()`. So you should be able to tell the difference between:

- `Activity` created for the first time
- `Activity` instance created after configuration change
- `Activity` instance recreated after Android killed it off and user returned to it

See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html?hl=en#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()

I'm not exactly sure of your requriements, but this information should help.

Comment: This helps me in adjusting the flow according to the scenario. Thank you for this information.

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel survives a configuration change since FragmentActivity stores it during `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance`, which is called during the process of configuration change of Activity. I think when "do not keep activities" mode is turned on, or when Activity is recycled by Android system, it does not belong to the process of configuration change. So `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` will NOT be called and ViewModel will not survive after Activity recreates.